# Big floor brackets size around fraction with small denominator

Tags: brackets, fractions, mathtools

i'm having issues with bracket formatting around fractions. For example, this code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    Core = \floor*{\dfrac{\floor*{\dfrac{\floor*{\dfrac{2*Level}{5}+2}*EffectiveAttack}{EffectiveDefense}}}{50}}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

produces this output :

[image]

I like that this fraction isn't squished vertically (thanks to `dfrac`) but it doesn't require such a wide space around the denominator, so i would like the outer brackets bottom branches to stop slightly below the denominator.

I'd like a way to produce something like this (sorry for the bad edit):

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with enclose your expression in `matrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
    \[
\text{Core} = 
    \floor*{\begin{matrix}
            \dfrac{\floor*{\begin{matrix}
                            \dfrac{\floor*{\dfrac{2*\text{Level}}{5}+2}*\text{EffectiveAttack}}
                                  {\text{EffectiveDefense}}
                           \end{matrix}}}
                  {50}
              \end{matrix}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Accepting your answer as it requires the least amount of modification from the writer's perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Some *ad hoc* functions, using the fact that you want to adjust fractions.

Below I also show a different rendering of the formula.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,delarray}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\newcommand{\adjustedfloor}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\fontdimen22\textfont2-\fontcharht\font`0+0.4ex}{%
    $\begin{array}\lfloor{@{}c@{}}\rfloor #1 \end{array}$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Core} = 
\adjustedfloor{
  \dfrac{
    \adjustedfloor{
      \dfrac{
        \floor*{\dfrac{2\cdot\mathrm{Level}}{5}+2}\cdot\mathrm{EffectiveAttack}
      }{
        \mathrm{EffectiveDefense}
      }% end of \dfrac
    }% end of \adjustedfloor
  }{50} % end of \dfrac
}% end of \adjustedfloor
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Core}=
\floor*{
  \frac{1}{50}
  \floor*{
    \dfrac{
      \floor{(2/5)\cdot\mathrm{Level}+2}\cdot\mathrm{EffectiveAttack}
    }{
      \mathrm{EffectiveDefense}
    }
  }
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :)